# Logstash won't take my multiline even with (?m)

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, grok

So I have this log message from a Cisco router:

```
Apr 15 10:51:26.824: %CRYPTO-4-PKT_REPLAY_ERR: decrypt: replay check failed
    connection id=777, sequence number=218932

Apr 15 11:00:03.261: %CRYPTO-4-PKT_REPLAY_ERR: decrypt: replay check failed
    connection id=777, sequence number=231456

Apr 15 11:05:00.525: %CRYPTO-4-PKT_REPLAY_ERR: decrypt: replay check failed
    connection id=789, sequence number=6509
```

Grok parses the bit until the \r\n just fine, but after it makes a new entry with parse failure. I have (?m) in front of the regex and it used to work before I updated to logstash 1.5.5.

What I find truly weird is that using http://grokconstructor.appspot.com I can't get it to match the whole thing even with (?m) at the beginning or a `(?<message>(.|\r|\n)*)` at the end. At rubular.com, both work just fine, but on grokconstructor and in my config they all stop matching at the new line.

Comment: You do not need `(?m)`, you need `(?<message>[\s\S]+)`. What is your intention? I  doubt matching the whole log is what you need.

Comment: grokconstructor still doesn't match it

Comment: Then try out [a multiline filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-multiline.html)

Comment: I would prefer to solve it with a regex.

Comment: Grokconstructor is configured to only parse separate lines. Try https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I see. That solves the constructor vs rubular mistery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config try to use the:

- multiline filter (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-multiline.html)
- multiline codec (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-
  UPDATED #1:
      multiline {
          pattern => "^%{CISCOTAG}.*"
          negate => "true"
          what => "previous"
          periodic_flush => false
      }

This will start a new log event whenever a line starts with text matching the %{CISCOTAG} pattern (e.g. Apr,...). All other lines (e.g. those starting with whitespace) will be appended to the previous event.

Comment: This would be problematic as I have some cheap switches that send syslog without a timestamp. That is the reason (+ high CPU usage) I told Wiktor I would like to solve it with a regex.

Comment: @Oxygen: You mean your log format varies depending on the switch model? If that's the case you can most likely tweak the multiline pattern. Can you elaborate on the types of format you need to match? What do you mean by high CPU usage?

Comment: The format is pasted in the original post. The pattern is: timestamp: %ciscotag: greedydata  By high CPU I mean it doesn't go below 50% usage. Stays close to 100% most of the time.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. Maybe I will take a new event only if it has a timestamp.

Comment: @Oxygen: hi please accept my answer if it was helpful:-)

Comment: I found the reason for the high CPU, it was over 1800 unallocated shards and another 1800 active shards. Cleaned it up and it runs like a charm. I will try the multiline plugin now and see how that works.

Comment: @Oxygen: ok cool, at least in my place multiline runs quite stable. good luck!

Comment: So I added this to the config: input {
        syslog {
                host => "10.1.1.1"
                port => 514
                type => "syslog"
  codec => multiline {
        pattern => "^\s"
        what => "previous"
       }
                }
 }
Yet it still doesn't work.